# Can C++ method names be qualified by the class name, in the header?

Tags: c++, syntax, declaration, classname

Simple question, is this valid C++:

```
class Foo
{
    void Foo::doSomething();
};
```

The point of the question: is that repeated use of the class name and double colon before the method name valid *inside* the class declaration?

I'm having issues compiling code that does this using g++ 4.2.3. I would love to see a reference to something describing the syntax here, before digging in and changing the code. Or downgrading the compiler; this does build with g++ 3.3.6.

The error I'm getting is (roughly):

```
Foo.h:3: error: extra qualification ‘Foo::’ on member ‘doSomething’
```

I did Google, but couldn't come up with something. I don't have the standard, and even if I did it would probably take me quite a while to find anything authoritative. I'm no C++ language lawyer.

Comment: Visual Studio (2008) accepts the "Foo::"

Comment: Yeah, I know ... But I'm trying to build the code using g++, and they are often different in what they accept and not. Or, from my point of view, VC seems to accept anything, while g++ can be picky. :)

Comment: I'd say the Foo:: was at best unnecessary and at worst not valid.  Therefore, in my opinion, you're perfectly justified in deleting it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I took a look at the standard, section 9.2 would be the relevant portion.  I'm not that great with BNF but I didn't see anything in the BNF for class members that would indicate this was allowed.  The identifier is even named "unqualified-id" in the BNF.

G++ changed the behavior in version 4.1, and apparently a lot of other compilers accepted this, but I've never seen this style used and I have no idea why anyone would do it.  Since it seems to not trigger an error on a pretty wide variety of compilers, there may be some historical reason for this style, but as far as I can tell it's indeed not valid.

The only good reference I found through Google was [this page](http://womble.decadentplace.org.uk/c++/syntax-errors.html), which just attempts to explain some of the changes in G++ 4.1.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very helpful answer. I've voted it up. I'll hold on a while before accepting, hoping to help people feel motivated enough to do more standards-searching. :)

Comment: I don't know why anyone would want to use this syntax either, but i know how it can magically appear. Sort of. Copy/paste from cpp to header file to inline the function and there you are.

Comment: Yes, that's what I suspect happened, too.

Answer (score 5):

Like Dan, I looked at the Standard without definitive results. I tried your code with [Comeau's on-line compiler](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) (considered the world's most standard compliant) and got:

> line 3: error: qualified name is not
>   allowed in member declaration

If you are interested in taking this further, I suggest posting a question on the [comp.lang.c++.moderated](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/topics?pli=1) newsgroup, as there are a lot more C++ language lawyers there than there are here.

Comment: Thanks! I voted this one up, but have now accepted Dan's answer, which I think makes sense and is fair.

Comment: I also use Comeau compiler for standard checking (and error reporting, as it is more expressive). That is a good advice to anyone: check code snippets with Comeau (online or buy it, as it is rather cheap)